# Add UIViewController below UITabBarController on iOS like youtube app

Tags: iphone, ios, view, uitabbarcontroller, slide

I have a `UITabBarController` with a few tabs. 
When I click a `UIButton` on first view (tab) I would like to slide whole `UITabBarController` out and show new `UIView` that is positioned bellow `UITabBarController`.

Something like it happens on youtube iPhone app when you start playing video.

I add UITabBarController to window in appDelegate like that:

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
```

**SOLUTION:**

```
[self.view.window insertSubview:welcomeViewController.view atIndex:0];
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0. options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{
    CGRect frame = self.tabBarController.view.frame;
    frame.origin.x += 400;
    self.tabBarController.view.frame = frame;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    //
}];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving your tab bar controller frame out of sight:

```
CGRect newFrame = tabBarController.view.frame;
newFrame.origin.y += winHeight;
[UIView
    animateWithDuration:0.5
    animations:^{
        tabBarController.view.frame = newFrame;
    }];
```

Comment: Ok, this works. But when I add new view to [self.view addSubview:] where on stack is this new view positioned? Is it bellow tabbarController or above?

Comment: How do I make sure that view is already bellow tabBarController when I slide it out?

Comment: I got it: [self.view.window insertSubview:newViewController.view atIndex:0];

Answer (score 1):

Add some animation for the `UITabBarController` on the click of the `UIButton` on first view (tab) ? Simply add the animation in them action of the button when the next View is called. For that you would have to put a timer also to let the `UITabBarController` ease out visibly

Comment: This is the question how to slide the whole UITabBarController (inlcuding tabs) out of the window... ?